# Looking for a translation of a German expression "mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit"

Tags: translation, german

In German language you use an expression *mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit* to say that you are almost one hundred percent sure/certain.

A particularity of that expression is that it has a subtility that I think comes from probability/mathematics; you say that you are not one hundred percent sure, but you can come arbitrarily close to certainty.
The expression also can make someone smile and/or shows a little bit of sophistication in the usage of the German language despite it's somewhat confusing meaning.
A probably wrong but literal translation could be something like *with probability bordering/verging on certainty*.

I use the expressions *almost certain*, *very sure*, *pretty sure*, etc. in this case, but I wonder....

In English language there is an expression that can come very close to the German expression?

Comment: You can use a statement based on mathematical probability terminology, but it wouldn't be idiomatic.

Comment: If you don't mind losing a bit in the translation, you could just say "with near certainty."

Comment: Also asked on [ell.se]: [Looking for a translation of a German expression “mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit”](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/77250/1216)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might just go with the literal translation ***with probability bordering on certainty***, which doesn't sound clunky at all. It actually sounds quite witty in English with exactly the same nod to mathematical sophistication.

As an alternative, you might use ***with confidence bordering on certainty***.

Roger Ebert uses "with a confidence bordering on certainty" in [this](http://www.rogerebert.com/reviews/only-you-1994) review of a film.

Actually, a google search of this latter phrase shows a lot of hits.

Comment: Why are your suggestions missing the indefinite article (“a”)?

Comment: I would usually omit them for better flow, since "with probability"and "with confidence" both have nice sounding iambic pentameter.

Answer (score 1):

*Certainty* can be modified by *moral* (or *certain* by *morally)* to indicate a degree of certainty short of absolute. Thus ***to a moral certainty*** might well do as an idiomatic translation of *mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit.*

OED s.v. ***moral***:

> 7. Of evidence, argument, etc.: based on a knowledge of the general tendencies of human nature, or of a particular person’s character; probable rather than demonstrative, sufficient to justify practical certainty. Of a belief: held as practically certain. Freq. in **moral certainty** *n.* a degree of probability so great as to admit of no reasonable doubt; a practical certainty on the basis of moral evidence.

In some fairly early usage, e.g., George Campbell’s *[Philosophy of Rhetoric](https://archive.org/details/philosophyofrhet00campuoft)* (1776) Chap. 5, this means any degree of certainty falling short of the absolute certainty of mathematical or logical *proof* or *demonstration,* including the by-word certainties of death and taxes and the strongest evidences of our senses and physical sciences concerning the world around us; but the definition offered by the *[American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moral)* (again, s.v. *moral)* suggests a degree of certainty considerably less than those:

> 6. Based on strong likelihood or firm conviction, rather than on the actual evidence: *a moral certainty.*

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=moral%20certainty%2Cmorally%20certain&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows these phrases declining in frequency since the all-time high associated with Campbell’s publication, but still current though a little *recherché,* as (we are told) is the German expression in question.